# Having Wordpress as landing page for Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, wordpress

I've met up with one of the digital marketing agency, and they actually recommend me to install a wordpress landing page as a marketing site ontop of my current magento site. They mentioned that it's for stronger SEO purpose as well as improve UI & UX. Just want to clarify if anyone is doing the similar thing, and could advise if it's advisable or not.

Comment: Define "install wordpress on top of my magento site". Do you want to have Wordpress as a store front and use Magento for the backend?

Comment: this is an epic nonsense.. they just probing you on "how much we can take from this deer". unfortunately this is a big problem of all times...

Comment: @ArjenMiedema to be more specific, it's a landing page/marketing site on top of my current magento site.

Answer (score 0):

As a general statement, this is nonsense.

The UI/UX always depends on the implementation of the Magento- or the WordPress-theme. It does not depend on the system itself.
The same goes for Onpage-SEO. If the Magento shop has a bad internal link structure, just change it.

We have also done things like this in the past: installed WordPress for blogging purposes, or to use it as a website and the shop for selling. In my experience, however, the pain is bigger than the gain.

Besides the employees of our clients who had to work with two systems now, the biggest problem we discovered was that optimizations and changes always had to be done twice. Want to optimize your HTML for the Google crawler? Do it in Magento and WordPress. Want to relaunch your design? Also Magento and WordPress. Want to make your site available for mobile users? Want to implement AMP? Always twice the effort.

If you want to blog in Magento, use one of the extensions that are available. If you need a CMS page hierarchy, you can work around this by using categories with static blocks. And if you want a completely different system with maybe a different layout that is not connected to the shop, install WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use only one platform. This will be good to manage as far as development and SEO or marketing is concerned.

You can either use **Magento** with blog extension or **Wordpress** with WooCommerce plugin.